# How to get a 'distanceField' in Atlas search?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, search, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

When I use $geoNear I can return a calculated distance by including the "distanceField" which is extremely useful when displaying items and their distance from a location. My code for this is:

```
$geoNear: {
    near: { 
        type: "Point", 
        coordinates: [ 
            req.body.position.lng , 
            req.body.position.lat 
        ] 
    },
    distanceField: "dist.calculated",
    maxDistance: req.body.distance,
    spherical: true
```

When using Atlas search, I need the same or similar "distanceField", but havn't been able to find a solution. I am open to other workarounds. Here's my $search pipeline:

````
    "$search": {
        "index": "searchResults",
        "compound": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "text": {
                        "query": `${req.body.query}`,
                        path: [
                            "name",  
                            "description", 
                            "tag", ],
                        "fuzzy": {
                            "maxEdits": 2,
                            "prefixLength": 4
                        }
                    }
                },
                {                            
                    "geoWithin": {
                        "circle": {
                            "center": {
                                "type": "Point",
                                "coordinates": [
                                    req.body.position.lng, 
                                    req.body.position.lat
                                ]
                            },
                            "radius": req.body.distance,
                        },
                        "path": "location",
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter":[{
                "text": {
                  "query": "Active",
                  "path": "active",
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}```
````